# Snowflake unable to convert an unexpected date format to the international standard

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, date-formatting

We have many type of date formats coming through our data lake, and we need to ingest them into data vault structure with the common date format YYYY-MM-DD.

within the ingest query we used COALESCE to return the first not null value:

```
COALESCE(TRY_TO_DATE(LOAD_DATE), DATE(LOAD_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY')) AS LOAD_DATE
```

Multiple errors returned:

> Date '13/7/2021' is not recognized

Or:

> Cannot parse '2022-06-01' as date with format
> 'DD/MM/YYYY'

We also used:

```
IFNULL(TO_DATE(LOAD_DATE), DATE(LOAD_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY'))
```

Also same errors returned.

We just tried with 'dd/mm/yyyy' and thought once it worked we can add more random formats to the coalesce but it seems to be not working anyway.

this is a small table where we tested the queries against:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE TEST (D varchar);
INSERT INTO TEST SELECT '13/7/2021';
INSERT INTO TEST SELECT date(current_timestamp());

select * from test;

select coalesce(try_to_date(D), date(D, 'dd/mm/yyyy')) from test;
```

the error returned:

> Can't parse '2022-07-26' as date with format 'dd/mm/yyyy'

**UPDATE**

Worked with `IFF`:

```
select iff(try_to_date(D) is null, date(d, 'dd/mm/yyyy'), date(d)) from test;
```

But is there any other convenient way to generalized over other unexpected formats?

Answer (score 1):

The reason the coalesce wasn't working is because the execution platform can and will evaluate multiple expressions in parallel to speed execution. It does not have to evaluate expressions in order left to right. The writer must be careful that none of the expressions can generate an error, even if the logic works in such a way that a prior expression will always evaluate to a non-null expression to the left of the expression that generates an error. You can potentially have the same problem with the IFF function or CASE WHEN blocks.

One way to ensure that you can't get an error is to use TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP with different timestamp formats. Notice that this SQL UDF never uses a conversion that generates an error on parse failure. Rather, it tests formats and when it finds a match uses TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP, which will return null instead of an error if there's a problem with the casting.

The logic is easy to follow and you can add and rearrange the formats in whatever order makes sense for your use case.

```
create or replace function TRY_MULTI_TIMESTAMP(STR string)
returns timestamp
language SQL
as
$$
    case
        when STR RLIKE '[A-Za-z]{3} \\d{2} \\d{4} \\d{1,2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}' then try_to_timestamp(left(STR, 20), 'MON DD YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
        when STR RLIKE '\\d{1,4}-\\d{1,2}-\\d{2} \\d{1,2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2} [A|P][M]' then try_to_timestamp(STR, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH12:MI:SS AM')
        when STR RLIKE '\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4}' then try_to_timestamp(STR, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
        when STR RLIKE '\\d{1,2}\\/\\d{1,2}\\/\\d{4} \\d{1,2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2} [A-Za-z]{2}' then try_to_timestamp(STR, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM')
        when STR RLIKE '\\d{1,2}\\/\\d{1,2}\\/\\d{4} \\d{1,2}:\\d{2}' then try_to_timestamp(STR, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI')
        when STR RLIKE '[A-Za-z]{3}, \\d{1,2} [A-Za-z]{3} \\d{4} \\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2} [A-Za-z]{3}' then try_to_timestamp(left(STR, len(STR) - 4) || ' ' || '00:00', 'DY, DD MON YYYY HH:MI:SS TZH:TZM')   -- From Snowflake "LIST" command
        when STR RLIKE '\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{2} \\d{1,2}:\\d{2} [A|P][M]' then try_to_timestamp(STR, 'MM/DD/YY HH12:MI AM')
        when STR RLIKE '[A-Za-z]{3} [A-Za-z]{3} \\d{2} \\d{4} \\d{1,2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2} GMT.*' then try_to_timestamp(left(replace(substr(STR, 5), 'GMT', ''), 26), 'MON DD YYYY HH:MI:SS TZHTZM')  -- Javascript
        else try_to_timestamp(STR) -- Final try without format specifier.
    end
$$;
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I didn't get the point of the first part of the answer. So coalesce will evaluate the 3 inputs at the same time ? That's why once a null found an error is thrown ?

Comment: Yes... Coalesce and similar functions / syntax may evaluate several expressions at once to speed execution. So a statement like this `coalesce(null, 1, 1/0)` could lead to an error even though as a human we would stop evaluating once we see the `1`. A function like that in a programming language would also normally evaluate left to right and never encounter an error, but an MPP database may evaluate all parts in parallel to save time.